# Function pointers in C: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: c, function, pointers, gcc

Consider the following private function declarations:

```
static void ParseCore(SI_32 num_param,const t_config_param config_param[CONFIG_PARAM_BUFFER_SIZE]);
static void ParseGnss(SI_32 num_param,const t_config_param config_param[CONFIG_PARAM_BUFFER_SIZE]);
static void ParseEaf(SI_32 num_param,const t_config_param config_param[CONFIG_PARAM_BUFFER_SIZE]);
static void ParsePps(SI_32 num_param,const t_config_param config_param[CONFIG_PARAM_BUFFER_SIZE]);
static void ParseImu(SI_32 num_param,const t_config_param config_param[CONFIG_PARAM_BUFFER_SIZE]);
```

Inside the definition of another function within the same source file, I initialize the following pointer:

```
void (*ParseConfigGeneric)(SI_32, t_config_param*) = NULL;
```

All of the following assignments get the warning indicated in the post's title:

```
ParseConfigGeneric = &ParseCore;
ParseConfigGeneric = &ParseGnss;
ParseConfigGeneric = &ParseEaf;
ParseConfigGeneric = &ParsePps;
ParseConfigGeneric = &ParseImu;
```

And here the output from GCC:

```
../src/core/time_mgmt.c: In function ‘ParseConfigFile’:
../src/core/time_mgmt.c:753:32: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             ParseConfigGeneric = &ParseCore;
                                ^
../src/core/time_mgmt.c:757:32: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             ParseConfigGeneric = &ParseGnss;
                                ^
../src/core/time_mgmt.c:761:32: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             ParseConfigGeneric = &ParseEaf;
                                ^
../src/core/time_mgmt.c:765:32: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             ParseConfigGeneric = &ParsePps;
                                ^
../src/core/time_mgmt.c:769:32: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
             ParseConfigGeneric = &ParseImu;
```

The code does compile and seems to work correctly, though. I looked up similar questions, but the problem is always that the pointer type differs from the original function's, but in this case they are all `void*` and the arguments match, so I can't tell what the problem is.

The call is as follows (no complaints from the compiler and I checked that the correct function gets called every time):

```
(*ParseConfigGeneric)(num_param, config_param);
```

Comment: I added the output from GCC. Also, I added that missing "const" and it was solved. I was being thrown off by GCC pointing at the assignment and not the argument itself as it usually does when I forget a const, but I guess this is a different case. Thanks! Could you please post your message as an answer so I can validate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the second argument differs between the functions, and the function-pointer variable.

In the functions it's a pointer to `const`, which it isn't in the function-pointer variable.

The type needs to be exactly equal.